# Javascript: How can i get a key value inside an array of a JSON object

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, jquery-callback

Hello i am building a web app and i use itunes search api.
So when i am searching for a specific track of an artist itunes return to me a JSON with some info related to the search term i put.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
 "resultCount":1,
 "results": [
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":271256, "collectionId":1025130620, "trackId":1025130621, "artistName":"Drake", "collectionName":"Hotline Bling - Single", "trackName":"Hotline Bling", "collectionCensoredName":"Hotline Bling - Single", "trackCensoredName":"Hotline Bling", "artistViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/drake/id271256?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/hotline-bling/id1025130620?i=1025130621&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/hotline-bling/id1025130620?i=1025130621&uo=4", "previewUrl":"http://a1586.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/172/Music6/v4/f6/2f/76/f62f7681-0f4c-3a9f-9aeb-2098297652f7/mzaf_7372296458390444020.plus.aac.p.m4a", "artworkUrl30":"http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music7/v4/2d/c5/31/2dc53130-44b8-8347-2f83-bce05ee8a649/source/30x30bb.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music7/v4/2d/c5/31/2dc53130-44b8-8347-2f83-bce05ee8a649/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music7/v4/2d/c5/31/2dc53130-44b8-8347-2f83-bce05ee8a649/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionPrice":1.29, "trackPrice":1.29, "releaseDate":"2015-07-31T07:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "trackCount":1, "trackNumber":1, "trackTimeMillis":267024, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Hip-Hop/Rap", "radioStationUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/station/idra.1025130621", "isStreamable":true}]
}
```

How am i able to get a specific value about "artistId" that is inside results array?

I use an $.getJSON call and in the callback i am unable to get this value.

Take a look in this [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/qpbp0gLe/4/) at the line 54 of javascript

Comment: I need artistId and trackId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant get Id like this

```
 var arr={
 "resultCount":1,
 "results": [
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":271256, "collectionId":1025130620, "trackId":1025130621, "artistName":"Drake", "collectionName":"Hotline Bling - Single", "trackName":"Hotline Bling", "collectionCensoredName":"Hotline Bling - Single", "trackCensoredName":"Hotline Bling", "artistViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/drake/id271256?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/hotline-bling/id1025130620?i=1025130621&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/hotline-bling/id1025130620?i=1025130621&uo=4", "previewUrl":"http://a1586.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/172/Music6/v4/f6/2f/76/f62f7681-0f4c-3a9f-9aeb-2098297652f7/mzaf_7372296458390444020.plus.aac.p.m4a", "artworkUrl30":"http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music7/v4/2d/c5/31/2dc53130-44b8-8347-2f83-bce05ee8a649/source/30x30bb.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music7/v4/2d/c5/31/2dc53130-44b8-8347-2f83-bce05ee8a649/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music7/v4/2d/c5/31/2dc53130-44b8-8347-2f83-bce05ee8a649/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionPrice":1.29, "trackPrice":1.29, "releaseDate":"2015-07-31T07:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "trackCount":1, "trackNumber":1, "trackTimeMillis":267024, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Hip-Hop/Rap", "radioStationUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/station/idra.1025130621", "isStreamable":true}]
}
arr.results.forEach(function(i,j){console.log(i.artistId)})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the fiddle you've provided, you try to access the artistId, by writing data.results.artistId, however results is an array, and as such you must access a property at one of it's indices. So something like `data.results[0].artistId` should work for you.